# Controlling position with nested divs (more than 2)

Tags: css

Up until now, I've only had to worry about positioning a child div inside a parent, in which case I was taught to do like so:

```
parent {
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

child {
bottom: 1px
position: absolute
}
```

The child here should be positioned inside, but at the bottom of the parent.  So it seems to me like the key for positioning a child inside the parent is the position:relative in the parent and the position: absolute in the child.

Now I'm trying to position a child div inside the existing child div, but since it is already set to position: absolute, I'm not sure what to do.  Using the example above, how would I position the second child at the bottom of the 1st child?

Answer (score 0):

If an absolutely positioned element is inside a parent with either `position: relative` or `position: absolute`, it will be positioned based on location of their parent container.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1">
        <div class="child-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #bbb;
}

.child-1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.child-2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

will work just fine.  Here's a link to a fiddle where you can play around with the results: http://jsfiddle.net/autoboxer/3583nazg/